# How to get two html forms working in one .php file?

Tags: php, html

Now i have 4 buttons on my page. They define different parameters. What i want to do, is use php switch case, and after pressing for example button1 i want the datetimepicker, and a chart appear as well. I read that i can manage with that problem using two html forms in one php file adding form id, but im only getting the first form to work properly while the second one seems to fail with sending the data using POST method. Below how i try to do this:

```
<form id="switch" action="data-from-database.php" method="post">
  <h2 align="center">Wybierz interesujący Cię przedział
    czasowy</h2></br>
  <div id="pudlo">
    <input type="submit" name="przycisk"
           class="input_wykresy" value="temperatura" form="switch">
    <input type="submit" name="przycisk"
           class="input_wykresy" value="wilgotność" form="switch">
    <input type="submit" name="przycisk"
           class="input_wykresy" value="ciśnienie" form="switch">
    <input type="submit" name="przycisk"
           class="input_wykresy" value="irradiancja" form="switch">
  </div>
</form>

<?php
//PHP part here is what i want to appear on the page after using switch
switch ($_REQUEST['przycisk'])
{
  case "temperatura":
    //Once again HTML part
    ?>
    <form id="picker" action="data-from-database.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="from_date"
             id="from_date" class="input_wykresy1" placeholder="Od" autocomplete="off">
      <input type="text" name="to_date" id="to_date"
             class="input_wykresy1" placeholder="Do" autocomplete="off">
      <input type="submit" name="filter" id="filter" value="Wyszukaj"
             form="picker" class="input_wykresy"/>
    </form>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["from_date"], $_POST["to_date"]))  // php code which i want to work in case
    {
      $handle = $link->prepare("SELECT temperatura, czaspomiaru FROM Pomiary
                                WHERE czaspomiaru BETWEEN'" . $_POST["from_date"] . "' AND
                                '" . $_POST["to_date"] . "'");
    }
    $dataPoints = [];
    //Best practice is to create a separate file for handling connection to database
    try
    {
      // Creating a new connection.
      // Replace your-hostname, your-db, your-username, your-password according to your database
      $handle->execute();
      $result = $handle->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
      if ($result)
      {
        foreach ($result as $row)
        {
          array_push($dataPoints, ["label" => $row->czaspomiaru, "y" =>
            $row->temperatura]);
        }
      }
      else
      {
?>
    <div>
      <h2>
        <center>Nie znaleziono pasujących rezultatów</center>
      <h2>
    </div>
<?php
      }
      $link = null;
    }
    catch (\PDOException $ex)
    {
      print($ex->getMessage());
    }
}
```

First form working properly, which i tested on buttons. Second one doesnt work, because when i press the submit button refering to datetimepickers, nothing shows on chart i assume no data been sent. I wonder how can i get the second form working?

Comment: Ok, I got what you mean now. It works for temperature. Where is the problem? - After edit not any more.

Comment: missing `<?php ?>` tags in your current snippet

Comment: @Quasimodo's clone the problem is that the second form, the one with picker id doesnt send the values and if isset condition doesnt work then

Comment: FWIW - forms are ancient history... look into ajax. It's simpler than you might think. Way simpler - especially when using jQuery. *With ajax (javascript/jQuery), you now have the ability to show/hide things on the fly and interact with the user.*

Comment: Syntax corrected and written more readable. The switch between forms works pretty well. 2nd form is shown when temperatura is pressed. So what is the actual problem now?

Comment: For one thing, the case has no break.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I saw this too, however, didn't want to alter code logics within the question, that's the author's part if a break is intended.

Comment: Change condition into `$_REQUEST['przycisk'] ?? ''` or you still get notices. Data is sent properly. `array (size=3)
  'from_date' => string '123' (length=3)
  'to_date' => string '455' (length=3)
  'filter' => string 'Wyszukaj' (length=8)` Since we do not have your database and the connection code, we do not get back data but `Call to a member function execute() on null` error.

Comment: You need to setup a [mcve] with hardcoded data sets you retrieved from database. Do a `var_export($dataPoints);`

Answer (score 0):

You might want a hidden field holding the name/value pair of the button taking you to the subform since the button is not part of that form.

```
<form id="picker" action="data-from-database.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="przycisk" value="temperatura">
  <input type="text" name="from_date"
         id="from_date" class="input_wykresy1" placeholder="Od" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" name="to_date" id="to_date"
         class="input_wykresy1" placeholder="Do" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="submit" name="filter" id="filter" value="Wyszukaj"
         form="picker" class="input_wykresy"/>
</form>
```

Or, since you do not use the submit button `name="filter"` in your PHP code, you could just alter that button.

```
<form id="picker" action="data-from-database.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="from_date"
         id="from_date" class="input_wykresy1" placeholder="Od" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" name="to_date" id="to_date"
         class="input_wykresy1" placeholder="Do" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="submit" id="filter" name="przycisk" value="temperatura"
         form="picker" class="input_wykresy"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using four radio buttons (instead of four submit buttons). Your site visitor(s) can select which radio button and submit. The code could easily be handled with `if`, `elseif`, `else` conditions, and the output could appear in one designated area, regardless of which radio button was selected.

```
<form id="switch" action="data-from-database.php" method="post">
  <h2 align="center">Wybierz interesujacy Cie przedzial
    czasowy</h2></br>
  <div id="pudlo">
    <input type="radio" name="przycisk" class="input_wykresy" value="temperatura">
    <input type="radio" name="przycisk" class="input_wykresy" value="wilgotnosc" >
    <input type="radio" name="przycisk" class="input_wykresy" value="cisnienie" >
    <input type="radio" name="przycisk" class="input_wykresy" value="irradiancja" >
    <input type="submit" value="submit">      
  </div>
</form>

<?php
  if (przycisk === "temperatura") {
    echo "yada";
  } elseif (przycisk === "wilgotnosc") {
    echo "yada";
  } elseif (przycisk === "cisnienie") {
    echo "yada";
  } else {
    echo "yada";
  }
?>
```